# How can I show touch swipe trails?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have created a simple HTML page using jQuery Mobile. the user can navigate between the pages by swiping the screen to the sides.

I want to show a finger trail whenever the user uses the swipe gesture (if you have played Fruit Ninja, you'll know what I mean.)

Any ideas how can I can implement it?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile allows you to get touch event coordinates (maybe start and end for swipe).

You can either use canvas, or a simple solution like a grid of div elements to show the swipe gesture trail.